# Creating a report showing which user belongs to which group

Tags: permissions, office-365, groups, user

Is there a way to create an excel report or something to show which user belongs to which group in a Office 365 tenant?

Answer (score 2):

This is your lucky day, since it's always been quite hard do develop using PowerShell. However, the script has already been published and is free to use. You find the script here: [List all Distribution Groups and their Membership in Office 365](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/List-all-Users-Distribution-7f2013b2).

```
################################################################################################################################################################  
# Script accepts 2 parameters from the command line  
#  
# Office365Username - Optional - Administrator login ID for the tenant we are querying  
# Office365Password - Optional - Administrator login password for the tenant we are querying  
#  
#  
# To run the script  
#  
# .\Get-DistributionGroupMembers.ps1 [-Office365Username admin@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com] [-Office365Password Password123] 
#  
#  
# Author:                 Alan Byrne  
# Version:                 2.0  
# Last Modified Date:     16/08/2014  
# Last Modified By:     Alan Byrne alan@cogmotive.com  
################################################################################################################################################################  

#Accept input parameters  
Param(  
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]  
    [string] $Office365Username,  
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]  
    [string] $Office365Password  
)  

#Constant Variables  
$OutputFile = "DistributionGroupMembers.csv"   #The CSV Output file that is created, change for your purposes  
$arrDLMembers = @{}  


#Remove all existing Powershell sessions  
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession  

#Did they provide creds?  If not, ask them for it. 
if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Office365Username) -eq $false) -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Office365Password) -eq $false)) 
{ 
    $SecureOffice365Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Office365Password -Force      

    #Build credentials object  
    $Office365Credentials  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Office365Username, $SecureOffice365Password  
} 
else 
{ 
    #Build credentials object  
    $Office365Credentials  = Get-Credential 
} 
#Create remote Powershell session  
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $Office365credentials -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection          

#Import the session  
Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber | Out-Null           

#Prepare Output file with headers  
Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject "Distribution Group DisplayName,Distribution Group Email,Member DisplayName, Member Email, Member Type" -Encoding UTF8  

#Get all Distribution Groups from Office 365  
$objDistributionGroups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited  

#Iterate through all groups, one at a time      
Foreach ($objDistributionGroup in $objDistributionGroups)  
{      

    write-host "Processing $($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName)..."  

    #Get members of this group  
    $objDGMembers = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySmtpAddress)  

    write-host "Found $($objDGMembers.Count) members..."  

    #Iterate through each member  
    Foreach ($objMember in $objDGMembers)  
    {  
        Out-File -FilePath $OutputFile -InputObject "$($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName),$($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.DisplayName),$($objMember.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.RecipientType)" -Encoding UTF8 -append  
        write-host "`t$($objDistributionGroup.DisplayName),$($objDistributionGroup.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.DisplayName),$($objMember.PrimarySMTPAddress),$($objMember.RecipientType)" 
    }  
}  

#Clean up session  
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

To run the script - type the following:

```
.\Get-DistributionGroupMembers.ps1
```